# Why fileformats option does not work with ftplugin file in vim?

Tags: windows, unix, vim, vim-plugin

In my `~/vimfiles/vimrc` file I have the following line of code:

```
 set fileformats=unix
```

In my `~\vimfiles\ftplugin\dosbatch.vim` file, there are two lines of code:

```
 setlocal fileformats=dos
 setlocal fileformat=dos
```

I have a file called *foo.bat*, which is a dosbatch filetype, and the file format is dos; I open it with vim and the screen displays `^M` characters, as follows:

```
@echo off^M
echo i am line1^M
echo i am line2^M
echo i am line3^M
pause
```

It seems that my two options in the `~\vimfiles\ftplugin\dosbatch.vim` file do not take effect. why?

Shouldn't   the values of option in the `~\vimfiles\ftplugin\dosbatch.vim` file override the `set fileformats=unix` configuration in vimrc?

In what order does vim read and execute the vimrc file, the ftplugin file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.Modify the file contents of dosbatch.vim as follows:

```
if !exists("dos_isreload")
    let dos_isreload = 1
    e ++ff=dos   
    setlocal fileformat=dos
    w
endif
```

Cause: When vim loads and executes dosbatch.vim, vim has loaded the contents of the file into the buffer, and used fileformate generated by `set fileformats=unix`.